# How do you run static content for using ( SpringBoot 2.x + weblogic + *.war ) from a classpath an application?

Tags: html, spring-boot, weblogic12c

I have a weblogic server that I run into Inlellij Idea for audit work of an application.
I made web-app based on SpringBoot 2.x. I am using Intellij Idea 2019 and there I configure a deploy my webapplication on weblogic 12.x.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>weblogic</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <version.apache.maven.plugins>3.8.1</version.apache.maven.plugins>
        <version.mapstruct>1.3.0.Final</version.mapstruct>

        <version.apache.common.lang3>3.9</version.apache.common.lang3>
        <version.apache.commons.text>1.8</version.apache.commons.text>
        <version.apache.commons.beanutils>1.9.4</version.apache.commons.beanutils>
        <version.datasource.proxy>1.6</version.datasource.proxy>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>


         <!--исключаем из компиляции встроенный Tomcat-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

</web-app>
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
                      http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1.4.0</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>/api</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

**src/main/webapp/index.html**

When I run weblogic by Intellij Idea I get index.html by url - http://localhost:7001/api

So, It works.

But I need more complex static content and I want to place it into an application classpath.

I made so…

**src/main/resources/templates/pages/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Weblogic!!!</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="st">
    Hello Weblogic!!!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**src/main/resources/static/css/style.css**

```css
.st{
    color: red;
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

And then…

**src/main/java/com/weblogic/weblogic/mvc/config/MyMvcConfig.java**

```java
package com.weblogic.weblogic.mvc.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MyMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/static/css/**",
                "/templates/pages/**")
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/",
                        "classpath:/static/css/",
                        "classpath:/templates/pages/");
    }
}
```

> But I get … Error 500--Internal Server Error
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:738)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:796)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:713)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.sendErrorIfNecessary(ErrorPageFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.getWriter(ErrorPageFilter.java:363)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:227)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)

who has any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You must use "template engine" – **Thymeleaf**. It doesn't work any other way (I would like to use pure **(html + bootstrap)**, but it's not clear how to configure it).

- pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>web.spring.boot.jar</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-spring-boot-jar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>web-spring-boot-jar</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**The structure of the static resources**

src/main/resources/static/css/style.css

src/main/resources/templates/index.html

src/main/resources/templates/pages/login/login.html

- *.properties

src/main/resources/application.properties

- These settings don't work.

```java
    spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api
    server.servlet.context-path=/api
    server.servlet.contextPath=/api
```

These settings could not be applied.

- **Configuration files** -  *.xml

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
            version="4.0">

   </web-app>
```

If this file is missing, then the deployment occurs with errors ( in the development environment, you can see this in the console).

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wls:weblogic-web-app
            xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
            http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
            https://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

        <wls:context-root>rst</wls:context-root>
        <wls:container-descriptor>
            <wls:prefer-application-packages>
                <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
            </wls:prefer-application-packages>
        </wls:container-descriptor>
    </wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

```xml
        <wls:context-root>rst</wls:context-root>
```

Here you need to be careful with choosing a name for the root context of the application (for example, if you chose a name for the context - **/web**, - > there will be an error, since this name is reserved somewhere).

```
                             Entry point
```

```java
    @SpringBootConfiguration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan

    public class WebSpringBootJarApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(WebSpringBootJarApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
            return builder.sources(WebSpringBootJarApplication.class);
        }

    }
```

- @SpringBootConfiguration
- @EnableAutoConfiguration
- @ComponentScan
- You must have these 3 annotations, otherwise nothing will work.

  The documentation says that **@SpringBootConfiguration**, replaces annotations:
- @Configuration,
- @EnableAutoConfiguration
- @ComponentScan

**@SpringBootConfiguration** - indicates that this class provides an application
**SpringBoot**

It can also be used as an alternative to the **@Configuration** annotation, because the configuration can be found automatically.

**@EnableAutoConfiguration**  - enables automatic configuration of Spring ApplicationContext by scanning class path components and registering beans that match different conditions.

That is, this annotation tries to guess and configure the beans that you may need.

Auto-configuration of classes, usually applied based on classpath
your application and on those beans that you have defined.

- When using the **@SpringBootConfiguration** annotation, the context configuration is enabled automatically and the annotation is added, which will not have any additional effect…
  But what I see here is quite different…
  Without this annotation, nothing works... That is, we don't get the requested resources.
- @ComponentScan  - Directive configures component scanning for the classes marked with @Configuration.
  Provides support in parallel using the configuration described in XML format in the element:

... But I didn't even specify the packages to scan....

And without specifying this annotation, I also can't access resources... ???

Why is that? I don't know…

What do I need to implement WebApplicationInitializer , - I don't know…

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-weblogic

- Contollers

src/main/java/web/spring/boot/jar/webspringbootjar/controller/index/IndexController.java

- IndexController

  ```java
  @Controller
  public class IndexController {

      @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
      public String index() {
          return "index";
      }
  }
  ```

src/main/java/web/spring/boot/jar/webspringbootjar/controller/login/LoginController.java

- LoginController

  ```java
  @Controller
  public class LoginController {


      @GetMapping(value = {"/log"})
      public ModelAndView showUsersPage() {

          return new ModelAndView("pages/login/login.html");
      }

  }
  ```

The creation of an artifact (Intellij Idea)
- Project Structure/Artifacts
- Alt + Insert
- Web Application: Exploded -> From module
 There is the path to the directory with your project will be specified.

You can also configure
- Project Structure/Facets

And then…

Run\Edit Configuration

Here you configure - weblogic…

URL to the app(in my case)
http://localhost:7001/rst/

The same access will be available when you migrate **.*war** from the development environment and deploy it to an external weblogic server.

If you start an external server, you get an error

This means that you need to run **maven** and  it must will make  a *.war-file…

**Also It doesn't work...**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { ServletContextConfig.class })
public class ServletContextConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory>
    webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
        return factory -> factory.setContextPath("/rootweb");
    }

}
```

- I suppose we only can use xml-configuration for servlet-context here.

If someone can add something, please specify what is wrong....

Can who has what ideas, about my issues which arose during this messages ....